# Register Dependency Injection (DI) Extension

Tags: symfony

In order to detected automatically a **DI Extension**, I tried to follow the [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/2.7/bundles/extension.html) , except that in my project I am not prefixing my folders with `Bundle` and I think I need to register the Extension manually.

This is my tree folder structure where I just created this `AppContextExtension`

`portal/src/Common
└── Infrastructure
    └── Symfony
        ├── Controller
        └── DependencyInjection
            └── AppContextExtension`

```
namespace Portal\Common\Infrastructure\Symfony\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Config\FileLocator;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\Extension;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Loader\YamlFileLoader;

class AppContextExtension extends Extension
{
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
       dump('it work');die;
    }
}
```

So Any idea how to register this Extension to container to make the `dump` alive ?? And why the Extension is not **autoregistred** !!!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49780704/symfony-appextension-not-loaded/49799531#49799531

Comment: Hmmm.  What Symfony version are you using?  If you still have an app/AppKernel then you pretty much need to make a bundle.  Newer versions have a src/Kernel.php file to kick things off.  You can still keep your existing layout.  Just need to explicitly specify the extension class in your bundle class file.

Comment: Thank you so mush the solution worked for me :) I really appreciate your help man.

Comment: By the way you can post a solution I will accepet it and vote for it, 
Ther's something I can't understand, normally my AppContextExtension is autoregistred, because I have under my services.yml `autoconfigure: true` and `autowire : true` that mean all my class are registred as services...why in my case the AppContext class it's not autoregistred !!

Comment: There is a big difference between defining a service in the container and having it called at the correct point in the boot process.

Comment: Can we register the Extension via the service.yml ?

Comment: Nope.  The extension class is what loads the various service and config file.  Kind of a catch-22.  And to be honest, I think you would be better off just adding a bundle class to what is in fact a bundle and calling it day.

Comment: When we work with last symfony version we prefre not prefixing with Bundle, espacially when the structure based on DDD design pattern, so adding a bundle folder that can not be good for the cohérence

Comment: As mentioned in my second comment, there is no need to change any of your namespaces or directory structure.  Having a Bundle in the namespace was always just a convention, not a requirement.  Adding a simple bundle file really is the "right" way to do things.  Keep in mind that the latest Symfony guidelines suggest not having an AppBundle.  Not eliminating bundles all together.  Having said that, it is your app of course and your choice.  Just want to make sure you understand the differences of the two approaches discussed.

Comment: Can you post a solution with the right namespaces !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think we kind of wandered off into la la land here but I maybe this is the example you asked for.

```
# portal/src/Symfony 
# could have been portal/src/Portal/Common/Infrastructure/Symfony
# but I got lazy
namespace Portal\Common\Infrastructure\Symfony;

use Portal\Common\Infrastructure\Symfony\DependencyInjection\AppContextExtension;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

# I suppose SymfonyBundle might be a better name 
class PortalBundle extends Bundle
{
    public function getContainerExtension()
    {
        return new AppContextExtension();
    }
}
```

The extension

```
namespace Portal\Common\Infrastructure\Symfony\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Extension\Extension;

class AppContextExtension extends Extension
{
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        dump('it work');die;
    }
}
```

config/bundles.php

```
Portal\Common\Infrastructure\Symfony\PortalBundle::class => ['all' => true],
```

composer.json

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "src/",
        "Portal\\Common\\Infrastructure\\Symfony\\": "portal/src/Symfony/"
    }
},
```

This all works as expected but your comments about autowire makes me suspect that you are trying to do something else completely. Autowire is generally for application defined services.  You would not autowire a bundle.

Enjoy

Comment: can you explain to me plz this 2 lines        "App\\": "src/",
        "Portal\\Common\\Infrastructure\\Symfony\\": "portal/src/Symfony/"

Answer (score 0):

In fact the solution is to inject the Extension class inside the AppKernel, because Extensions can be loaded using `Kernel::build()`.

```
//AppKernel.php

class AppKernel extends Kernel
{
    //

    protected function build(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $container->registerExtension(new \Portal\Common\Infrastructure\Symfony\DependencyInjection\AppExtension());
    }
```

Thank's for @Cerad how helped me to find my way.